# ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: user_id):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, heroku

My app on Heroku shows this error:
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

So I ran Heroku logs and guessed this could be the problem:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: user_id):
app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:14:in `new'
```

My Pins controller

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]



def index
    @pins = Pin.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @pin = current_user.pins.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)
    if @pin.save
      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end



def update
    if @pin.update(pin_params)
      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @pin.destroy
    redirect_to pins_url
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_pin
      @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @pin = current_user.pins.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to pins_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this pin" if @pin.nil? 
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def pin_params
      params.require(:pin).permit(:description, :image)
    end
end
```

Anything wrong? Am I looking at the right place to debug?

Turns out I didn't do heroku run rake db:migrate. Thanks guys for that. Another error came up.

```
ArgumentError (missing required :bucket option):
app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:22:in `create'
```

Is this tied to Amazon Web Services?

Comment: Do you have user_id in pins table? If you do, did you run the migrations?

Comment: +1 for `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: Turns out I haven't run heroku run rake db:migrate. Have done it now. But ran into another problem (added above)

Comment: Ok guys, I managed to resolve the last error. :). I went into and changed :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'], to :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'] in config/environments/production.rb. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

You combined 2 issues into one question. For the first problem with the unknown attribute user_id you need to run:

`heroku run rake db:migrate`.

For the second problem with your `ArgumentError (missing required :bucket option):` error you need to set the heroku config to:

`heroku config:set S3_BUCKET_NAME=nameOfYourBucket`

Answer (score 0):

I'd go in New action for plain

```
@pin = Pin.new
```

You are using your Create action to add the values from relations, so it should work fine

Other then that, use .new in New and .build in Create